# How do I add one constructor to this driver program so that it works with both arraylist and linked list?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

The methods written are here, I'll just paste their names to be succinct:

```
public void clear();

public boolean contains(E e);

public E get(int index);

public int indexOf(E e); //returns first E e

public boolean isEmpty();

public int lastIndexOf(E e);

public boolean remove(E e);//removes first E e in list

public E remove(int index);

public E set(int index, E e);

public int size();

public boolean addAll(MyList<? extends E> l);
```

So I created a MyArrayList and MyLinkedList class to implement these methods for both arraylists and linked lists.

Here is the driver made for ArrayLists that I'm supposed to add something to to make it work for linked lists:

```
public class MyArrayListDriver { 
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
MyArrayList<String> arrayList1 =    new MyArrayList<String>(); //       Constructor 1
MyArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new MyArrayList<String>(5); // Constructor 2

arrayList1.add("Monday"); // 1
arrayList1.add("Tuesday");
arrayList1.add("Thursday");
arrayList1.add("Saturday");

System.out.println(arrayList1);

arrayList1.add(2, "Wednesday"); // 2
arrayList1.add(4, "Friday");
arrayList1.add(6, "Sunday");

System.out.println(arrayList1);

System.out.println("There are " + arrayList1.size() + " days of the week."); // 3

System.out.println(arrayList1.get(5) + " is my favorite day of the week!"); // 4

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

System.out.println("\n");

arrayList2.add("Uncle John");
arrayList2.add("Tom");
arrayList2.add("Pa");
arrayList2.add("Jim Casy");
arrayList2.add("Ma");

if(arrayList2.contains("Jim Casy")) // 5
{
System.out.println(arrayList2.get(3) + " says, \"Don't break up the      fambly.\"");
```

}

```
if(arrayList2.indexOf("Jim Casy") == 1) // 6
System.out.println("One is the lonliest number.");
else
 System.out.println("Not alone today...");
arrayList2.remove("Jim Casy"); // 7
System.out.println(arrayList2 + "... Goodbye Jim Casy.");

arrayList2.clear(); // 8

if(arrayList2.isEmpty()) // 9
  {
System.out.println(arrayList2 + "\nSee ya Joads; I hope California treats you    well!");
```

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
System.out.println("\n");

MyArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new MyArrayList<String>(arrayList1); // Constructor 3

System.out.println(arrayList3 + " is the third ArrayList.");

arrayList3.remove(2); // 10

arrayList3.add(2, "Assembly Day");

System.out.println("Schedule: " + arrayList3);

arrayList3.set(5, "Standardized Test Day"); // 11

System.out.println("Revised Schedule: " + arrayList3);

for(int i = 0; i < arrayList3.size(); i++)
{
if(i % 2 == 0)
{
arrayList3.set( i, "Monday");
```

}
}

```
System.out.println(arrayList3);

System.out.println(arrayList3.lastIndexOf("Monday") + " is rad..."); // 12

System.out.println("\n");

arrayList2.addAll(arrayList3); // 13

System.out.println(arrayList2);
} }
```

Again, how can I make this driver meant for arraylist function for a linked list as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit them from one class(better interface), let's call it:

```
public interface MyList<T>{
//your methods without implementation
}
```

And in your classes write(for example on MyArrayList):

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements MyList<T>{\\implementations...}
```

Then in your Driver do something like:

```
MyList<String> list;
if(//define when you want to use linked list){
  list = new MyLinkedList<String>();
} else {
  list = new MyArrayList<String>();
}
```

and then your `list` will be instance of either linked or array list, so when you call methods on it, it will execute them using implementation in the class you've specified during construction

Links to read: [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)